# Set FLASK_APP after restructuring Flask into package

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I cannot set the FLASK_APP variable after restructuring it into a package, it gives an error Could not locate a Flask application. Use the 'flask --app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory.

Below is the file organization,

[File organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJEwp.png)

And the contents of the `__init__.py` are as follows which is in the package flaskblog as shown above.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app= Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']= ''
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///site.db'
db= SQLAlchemy(app)

from flaskblog import routes
```

And the contents of the `run.py` are as follows

```
from flaskblog import app

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run(debug= True)
```

I want to set the FLASK_APP environment variable so that I can activate the SQLite database using flask shell. However while setting the (.venv) PS C:\Users\sample projects\flask_blog> set FLASK_APP=flaskblog

I get

```
Usage: flask shell [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask shell --help' for help.

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. Use the 'flask --app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory.
```

But the python run.py gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by using creating a separate file `.flaskenv` in the project directory and then setting the FLASK_APP environment variable inside the the file.

In '.flaskenv'

`FLASK_APP=flaskblog`

Then installing `pip install python-dotenv`

Then running `flask shell` worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your env variables like

bash

```
set FLASK_APP=flaskblog
```

powershell

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "flaskblog"
```

And also i wouldnt call  `__run__.py`, i would call simply `run.py`